# How do i define macros in NASM x86

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm

I'm trying to implement couple of macros for x86 project.
I just moved from MARS mips assembly so dont judge my incompetence.
I think I'm doing everything as in this guide `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_macros.htm`

```
  %macro assign a,b
       mov ax, [b]
       mov [a], ax
  %endmacro
```

This is the error i get:
fun.asm:21: error: `%macro' expects a parameter count

I've also tried doing this with "%" before values (a and b) but it only produced syntax errors

Could anybody point out what exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: `copy16` would be a better name for that macro.  `assign` sounds like something that should happen at assemble time, especially given that NASM has a `%assign` preprocessor directive!!  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can directly give names to the arguments like that. Instead you supply the number of arguments you expect and refer to the with `%1`, `%2`, etc. So your macro would look like this:

```
%macro assign 2
       mov ax, [%2]
       mov [%1], ax
%endmacro
```

There's more details in the [NASM manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.3).

Comment: Yeah that's misssing component of my uderstanding of NASM macros.
Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @MarcinTarłowski I missed it too, that's why I had to write €ASM which fills that gap: https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#MacroInstructions